# I am re- pointing between patio slabs using soft sand and a standard cement.The cement recommends 1 : 5 but should it be 1:3 for these slabs? I

Tags: mortar

I am re- pointing between patio slabs using soft sand and a standard cement.The cement recommends ratio of 1:5,but should this be 1:3 for patio slabs?

Answer (score 1):

To give a quick answer, if you have masonry cement yes, 1 to 3 for the mix. If you have portland cement, it needs to stay at 1 to 5.

Portland is much stronger than masonry cement which has lime in it I believe. If you use too much portland with the sand, the mix will readily crack due to shrinkage.

Comment: I agree I have made stepping stones with molds in the past at first I did use extra Portland cement in my mix everything looked good , but the friend I borrowed the molds came over and took 1 look and said two much those won’t last. He was right the first 2 batches did not hold up they started cracking after 2 -3 years all the others I made are still there 20+ years later.